# Correct usage of AntiForgery token in ASP.NET 5 in SPA application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application, antiforgerytoken

In previous version of ASP.NET during SPA application the idea of AntiForgey token was following:

- add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` on the page
- add `__RequestVerificationToken` to the request
- ovverride AuthorizeAttribute as `ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`.

I don't really understand the authorization requirements (is there some good information source?) in ASP.NET 5 but looks like new behavior should be like this:

- add `asp-anti-forgerytaghelper`
- add `__RequestVerificationToken` to the request
- *here should be the new requirement.*

The question is: how to write this new authorization requirement and remove standard one? Could someone give some advice or point me on some example?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like I need to create custome middleware and check if it's json to use my way or use standard await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);
But still not sure about it. Something like this https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/dev/samples/AntiforgerySample/FormPostSampleMiddleware.cs

Answer (score 1):

With MVC6, if you use something like this:

```html
<form asp-controller="Account" 
      asp-action="Login">
</form>
```

You will automatically get :

```html
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="....">
</form>
```

`asp-antiforgery` would only be used if you want to deactivate that behavior.

As for the validation itself, it was added when you did `app.AddMvc(...)` in your `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` method.

In fact there's a bunch of stuff that is being added and if you are curious, you can [check out the code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/DependencyInjection/MvcViewFeaturesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L79)!

If you really to generate this from an Action using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) then you could have a controller that depends on `IHtmlGenerator` and generate your token that way.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I agree with this, but it works only with MVC6 as you mentioned. I'm asking about SPA. How I should handle `__RequestVerificationToken` which was sent by Angular for instance, not as a form submit.

Comment: Updated answer. Basically, it's generated from `IHtmlGenerator` which depends on `IAntiForgery` which depends on a whole different kind of crazy dependencies. If you need to ensure it is present that's the way to do it. Or you could just turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

In AspNetCore 1.1.0.0 (Maybe also in earlier versions) with a SPA scenario this is actually quite easy:

Make sure you deliver your index page from a .cshtml view and just add

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

If you are using jquery you can then read this token and make sure it is sent with all future non-get requests inside a http-header

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    if (options.type.toUpperCase() != "GET") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());
    }
});
```

Inside your controller method, just add

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string TestAntiForgery()
{
   return "success";
}
```

If you want/must use a differen header you can change it like this in configureServices:

```
services.Configure<AntiforgeryOptions>((options) =>
{
    // Configure a different header here
    options.HeaderName = "otherHeaderName";
});
```